# Retrieving file data in chunks using Web API for display in browser (WIP)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, blob

I have this working but I want to share this out to see if I missed anything obvious and to solve a mystery as to why my file chunk size has to be a multiple of 2049.  The main requirements are:

- Files uploaded from website must be stored in SQL server, not as files
- Website must be able to download and display file data as a file (opened in a separate window.
- Website is angularjs/javascript SPA, no server side code, no MVC
- API is Web API 2 (again not MVC)

I'm just going to focus on the download part here.  Basically what I'm doing is:

1. Read a chunk of data from SQL server varbinary field
2. Web API 2 api returns file name, mime type and byte data as a base64 string.  NOTE - tried returning byte array but Web API just serializes it into base64 string anyway.
3. concatenate the chunks, convert the chunks to a blob and display

VB library function that returns a dataset with the chunk (I have to use this library which handles the database connection but doesn't support parameter queries)

```
Public Function GetWebApplicationAttachment(ByVal intId As Integer, ByVal intChunkNumber As Integer, ByVal intChunkSize As Integer) As DataSet

    ' the starting number is NOT 0 based
    Dim intStart As Integer = 1
    If intChunkNumber > 1 Then intStart = ((intChunkNumber - 1) * intChunkSize) + 1
    Dim strQuery As String = ""
    strQuery += "SELECT FileName, "
    strQuery += "SUBSTRING(ByteData," & intStart.ToString & "," & intChunkSize.ToString & ") AS ByteData "
    strQuery += "FROM FileAttachments WHERE Id = " + intId.ToString + " "
    Try
        Return Query(strQuery)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ...
    End Try
End Function
```

Web API business rules bit that creates the file object from the dataset

```
...
    result.FileName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FileName"].ToString();
    // NOTE: Web API converts a byte array to base 64 string so the result is the same either way
    // the result of this is that the returned data will be about 30% bigger than the chunk size requested
    result.StringData = Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ByteData"]);
    //result.ByteData = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ByteData"];
    ... some code to get the mime type
    result.MIMEType = ...
```

Web API controller (simplified - all security and error handling removed)

```
public IHttpActionResult GetFileAttachment([FromUri] int id, int chunkSize, int chunkNumber) {
    brs = new Files(...);
    fileResult file = brs.GetFileAttachment(appID, chunkNumber, chunkSize);
    return Ok(file);
}
```

angularjs Service that gets the chunks recurively and puts them together

```
    function getFileAttachment2(id, chunkSize, chunkNumber, def, fileData, mimeType) {
        var deferred = def || $q.defer();
        $http.get(webServicesPath + "api/files/get-file-attachment?id=" + id + "&chunkSize=" + chunkSize + "&chunkNumber=" + chunkNumber).then(
            function (response) {
                // when completed string data will be empty
                if (response.data.StringData === "") {
                    response.data.MIMEType = mimeType;
                    response.data.StringData = fileData;
                    deferred.resolve(response.data);
                } else {
                    if (chunkNumber === 1) {
                        // only the first chunk computes the mime type
                        mimeType = response.data.MIMEType;
                    }
                    fileData += response.data.StringData;
                    chunkNumber += 1;
                    getFileAttachment2(appID, detailID, orgID, GUID, type, chunkSize, chunkNumber, deferred, fileData, mimeType);
                }
            },
            function (response) {
                ... error stuff
            }
        );
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

angular controller method that makes the calls.

```
    function viewFile(id) {
        sharedInfo.getWebPortalSetting("FileChunkSize").then(function (result) {
            // chunk size must be a multiple of 2049 ???
            var chunkSize = 0;
            if (result !== null) chunkSize = parseInt(result);
            fileHelper.getFileAttachment2(id, chunkSize, 1, null, "", "").then(function (result) {
                if (result.error === null) {
                    if (!fileHelper.viewAsFile(result.StringData, result.FileName, result.MIMEType)) {
                        ... error
                    }
                    result = {};
                } else {
                    ... error;
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

And finally the bit of javascript that displays the file as a download

```
    function viewAsFile(fileData, fileName, fileType) {
        try {
            fileData = window.atob(fileData);
            var ab = new ArrayBuffer(fileData.length);
            var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);    // ia provides window into array buffer
            for (var i = 0; i < fileData.length; i++) {
                ia[i] = fileData.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            var file = new Blob([ab], { type: fileType });
            fileData = "";
            if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) // IE10+
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, fileName);
            else { // Others
                var a = document.createElement("a"),
                    url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                a.href = url;
                a.download = fileName;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    document.body.removeChild(a);
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                }, 0);
            }
            return true;
        } catch (e) {
            ... error stuff
        }
    }
```

I see already that a more RESTful approach would be to use headers to indicate chunk range and to separate the file meta data from the file chunks.  Also I could try returning a data stream rather than Base64 encoded string.  If anyone has tips on that let me know.

Comment: I can already see this was the wrong way to do this.  should this be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Well that was entirely the wrong way to go about that.  In case it helps here's what I ended up doing.

- Dynamically create the href address of an anchor tag to return a file (security token and parameters in query string)
- get byte array from database
- web api call return response message (see code below)

This is much faster and more reliable, but provides less in the way of progress monitoring.

business rule method uses...

```
...
file.ByteData = (byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ByteData"];
...
```

web api controller

```
public HttpResponseMessage ViewFileAttachment([FromUri] int id, string token) {
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    ... security stuff
    fileInfoClass file = ... code to get file info
    response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(file.ByteData);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") {
            FileName = file.FileName
        };
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(file.MIMEType);
    return response;
```

This could even be improved with streaming